# What are possible values for TERM in a docker container?

Tags: terminal, docker, xterm

[The documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/) says:

> The following environment variables are set for Linux containers:
>
> `TERM`: `xterm` if the container is allocated a pseudo-TTY

But apparently it supports 256 colors, or not? So I can probably set `TERM=xterm-256color` (granted that `ncurses` is installed, and the value exists in the `terminfo` database). Any other values?

**UPD** `xterm-256color` seems to work. You might want to use it to tell applications that 256 colors are available. Some applications might get away without this.